# how to create a div around a pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which is in a pre tag. the output is this:

```
<div class="Message">
   <pre class="Codeblock>
       <!-- code goes here -->
   </pre>
</div>
```

Now I want to create a div around this pre block like this:

```
<div class="Message">
   <div id="firstblock">
     <pre class="Codeblock>
         <!-- code goes here -->
     </pre>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried already this:

```
var extradiv = document.createElement('div');
extradiv.id = 'firstblock';
$('.Message').prepend(extradiv);
```

But that creates the div open end close before the pre tag

Comment: are you using jQuery or plain JS? Because there's no jQuery tag yet you are using jQuery syntax

Comment: What I would do here, is to find the parent element of the `pre` tag, insert the wrapper appended to the parent, remove and re-insert the pre into the new wrapper.

Comment: I am using both because jquery is already loaded for the Message class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) will surround the `pre` tag for you:

```
$('.Message .Codeblock').wrap('<div id=firstblock></div>');
```

Comment: this works perfect! thank you